# Is free disk space in a LVM volume group required?

Tags: lvm

I installed Proxmox and experimenting around with it and noticed that it keeps some free space on the LVM volume group by default. I wonder why this is? Does LVM need this or something? because is was simply able to allocate the empty space to logical volume so i use 100% of my volume group.

When its not required but recommended, i'm curious why this is. Off course i Googled this first but was not able to find a clear explanation about this for this reason i drop the question here..

Comment: I am 99.9% certain its not required - why it would be there is speculation. The ability to do snapshots? Emergency expansion? Under provisioning for SSD?

Comment: Ok, like what i thought. -- Under provisioning for SSD? is this best practice/recommended? i thought SSD's have "emergency space" on board that's not included in the "available space"? If this is incorrect, does an SSD care about dead clusters and use "under provisioned space" for this automatically?

Comment: I have not heard recommendations to under provision an SSD, but I'm pretty sure wear levelling is throughout the disk, so any unused space will be used. I understand SSDs spread the load around the "disk" - what the controller sees is an abstraction.